# A way to catch if user leave chat teleram bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

i find new_chat_participant or left_chat_participant  but that work only in group chat.
I've used the new_chat_members event to know weather a new user joined the bot or not. But seems that this event will not be emitted.
But using the message event I will get the below result:

`{"message_id":4,"from":{"id":324299944,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"foo","last_name":"bar","language_code":"en"},"chat":{"id":324299944,"first_name":"foo","last_name":"bar","type":"private"},"date":1513786467,"text":"/start","entities":[{"offset":0,"length":6,"type":"bot_command"}]`

i write bot with java script and in the google app script .
**my oreginal problem is how to find out a user stop or left the bot**

Answer (score 3):

For some reason that I was not able to find in the docs telegram **doesn't send updates when user leaves the private group. It only does it for public groups** (ex supergroups). Another curious thing is that the update message contains "left_chat_participant" and "left_chat_member" objects with the exact same info, probably for some bc

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately currently there is no way to found out the user block the bot. new_chat_participant or left_chat_participant presented in telegram bot API v3 for completely another purpose.